# How to keep my web app running after exiting from EC2 CLI

Tags: python, linux, machine-learning, amazon-ec2, streamlit

I have tried tmux to keep my Streamlit app running on my AWS EC2 instance but it is not working,
I am new to AWS and Linux, anybody ??

Comment: https://ss64.com/bash/screen.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use **screen** Utility.

### Start new Screen

You can start a new screen by the following command

```
screen
```

Then Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to Start using Screen.

### Detach Screen

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> same time as to Detach from the screen.

### List Detach screen

You can list Running Screen by

```
screen -ls
```

### Reattach existing Screen

You can Reattach screen by

```
screen -r <Screen_name>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like PM2 https://pm2.keymetrics.io/, it helps you run your processes 24/7, even when you are logged out of your EC2 instance.

Answer (score 1):

First <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and then <kbd>D</kbd>, but not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. Please be carefully..

Comment: isn't it supposed to be <ctrl>+<a>?